# Eclipse doesn't show classes within packages

Tags: eclipse, class, maven, svn, package

After months of using Eclipse (latest Kepler release) on Ubuntu (13.10), after rebooting from to a sudden loss of power on my laptop, now Eclipse won't let me access java classes within their packages. It simply just shows the packages names but when I click on these the java classes are not showing.

Please note that even though I have several Maven projects working, this happens only on one specific project.

[image: Eclipse packages]

Steps so far:

1) I checked the permissions of all the java files and the directories.

2) Tried updating the project but no luck, also reverted back to my an earlier version (SVN) but didn't help either.

3) I tried deleting .eclipse and re-installing Eclipse and importing my projects, but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.

4) I have checked the .classpath file which seems ok.

5) Recursively 'touch' all the files, but still nothing.

I believe that this is a Maven + Eclipse related issue but I have ran out of options here, so I am open to suggestions. Thanks...

Comment: Please post a screenshot, maybe you're in a wrong view, perspective, etc. Also check `workspace/.metadata/logs`.

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't. It won't let me since my reputation is <10...

Comment: There you go, I upvoted your question so you should be able to post images ;-)

Comment: It still didn't let me upload the image, so I posted a link instead. Thanks

Comment: Those are your test folders. Are you sure they aren't empty? Do you have specified the same output folder for it (under properties)?

Comment: Positive, the classes exist. I have triple checked their locations and file permissions. Neither the src or test packages are shown...

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not a problem of the project but of the workspace metadata. Please create a new workspace and important the project there. Are you able to browser the package explorer there?

Comment: As mentioned in the 2nd step, I imported the projects again when I re-installed eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Those are empty packages as you know. we need to right click on those packages and create class then you would probably see classes.

In case u still can't see classes then Go to Window->show view->Package explorer

you will be able to see packages along with classes tagged. if you have created any.

[click here to see Image view of above settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxaUA.png)